# Stuck at "Downloading Language Packs..." while installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, dvd

I am installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It is stuck at the point where it says "Downloading Language Packs...".  The timing of the freeze seems random. It has been stuck for over 2 hours since starting the download.

Is there any way to skip this downloading with out terminating installation?

Further info: I am installing through DVD, if that matters at all, and I have an active internet connection that is working well (checked it in my friend's laptop, since it is shared, download speed about 50kbps).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the solution...
At the place where it says "Downloading language packages", there is a arrow to the left of message.

By clicking on array, there appears a small window at bottom and a bottom at right most side at the level of "Downloading language packages" that says "Skip", by pressing that button one can skip that step.

I cant paste a screen shot,as system is installing Ubuntu.

Comment: You can paste a screenshot if you select Try Ubuntu and then install it from a full environment.

Comment: Note that the skip button is initially visible.  Clicking it once makes the small window appear.  Clicking it a second time makes the small window and the skip button disappear, but it does not stop downloading.  *Then* you can click the arrow to show the skip button and click it a third time to make it stop.  All this after telling it *not* to download updates in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

As the previous answer has stated, you can click the "**Skip**" button to opt-out from downloading and installing the language packages during installation.

**OR**

You can disconnect first from the Internet before you start the installation, you can always perform an update right after installation and reboot by running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I found that clicking on the arrow before the"downloading language packs" works well. Click on the arrow, then the 'Skip' option appears. Next click on Skip.

I had already waited 2 hours for the language pack download to finish and it was still showing 184 minutes left.

Now I'm using Ubuntu without the pack and as I restarted the PC, I get the "*Finish the language pack*" option which means I can download them now.

Answer (score -1):

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 and it took me about an hour to completely download and install those language packs. I have connection with downloading speed of 100Kbps. I think you'll have to wait for the language packs to download. It's very irritating but you have to bear it (like I did) :)

Comment: Is there no way to skip this?

Comment: there can be. But I don't know any way to skip that.