# How to disable the download of language packs while installing Kubuntu

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu

I am installing Kubuntu 12.04 from a usb drive and it is downloading a lot of language packs. My internet speed is too slow and  it would take another 45 minutes to install them. The cancel button doesn't seem to work. How can I stop downloading the language packs and complete my installation?

Comment: I just approved the edit kind of window , is it ok to do it

Comment: Sirs and Teachers please help little bit faster since , i don't know should i cancel the installation now , since i want to leave for my class :))

Comment: You should click the SKIP button not Cancel. Or disconnect from Internet before you begin the installation.

Comment: @msPeachy - Hi , the skip or cancel button doesn't works while downloading Lang packs, so i asked how to do that.I am afraid that disconnecting may cancel my installation afterwards, thank you for commenting :) ....But isn't the cancel or skip button is expected to move forward without downloding it , is my download OS faulty or software is bugged, or mouse click is faulty somehow ...

Comment: It should. It will not cancel the installation, if you disconnect before you even begin the installation, that's what I think.

Comment: If the button is provided , isn''t it suppose to work ...?? . Anyway i installed it with 2 + hours into installation downloading language packs . Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

If you still need this, have look at:

[Ubuntu installation issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166063/ubuntu-installation-issue)

It's not at all obvious where the skip button is, but this explains it well. And it works!

HTH
Martin

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply disconnect your wifi before you install, then once the install completes run update manager to download all updates etc.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping , but i am afraid that disconnecting may cancel my installation afterwards, thank you for commenting.