# Downloading langage packs makes the installation process take a long time.

Tags: language-support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How can I remove the Translation entries in apt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74653/how-can-i-remove-the-translation-entries-in-apt)
> [How to disable the download of language packs while installing Kubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174892/how-to-disable-the-download-of-language-packs-while-installing-kubuntu)

When installing while connected to the internet, downloading language packs can take a long time.

> (original message) :
>
> Why mandatory install slow load huge Language Pack.Native user
> applaud.Chosen at install already practical.Window install on request
> only.

Comment: I am not understanding , Question was not clear . could you explain more .

Comment: Maybe someone with more knowledge may come along, but this language pack business does take up a significant part of the installation process.

Answer (score 3):

I have to agree.  The best thing to do if you have a slow internet connection is not let the install programme connect to the internet and update while installing.  Connect after the installation is complete and do the updates then.  Install time should be 20 minutes or even less depending on the speed of your computer.

Comment: To Fabricator4.A novice to Ubuntu OS.Use liveCD to install side to WIN.Dialogue indicate Select language and 2 other:Updates N Software and not clicked.When install 472 items appear and jam at language section.Question MANDATORY mean is it a package install.I choose a language I understand for install.Language is useful if communication between people is understood.Otherwise it is blabbering of tongues in unknown dialogue.A Korean or Hindu will applaud their language is offered.These extra language files wont see light so delete to gain space or keep?I wont mind 2 hours but now 8 hours.

Comment: Unplug network before install - will be 0 hours.  The install will still be in your language.  You can update the language packs later.

Comment: Or press the "Skip" button (it's on the right).