# How to stop the download/installation of language packs

Tags: fonts, language-support, input-language

I recently installed the Unity 8 version of Unity, but was shocked by the amount of foreign-language-related software packages that were going to be installed:

[image]

and that's not even all of them, there were more higher up in the list.

Now, I don't have the fastest internet (it's nearly dial-up speeds - 81 Kb/s is what I max at) so I'm always looking for ways to cut down on download times and the download/installation of these language packs adds a lot to that.

Now, there are a few different questions already on the site regarding this issue, [How to disable the download of language packs while installing Kubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174892/how-to-disable-the-download-of-language-packs-while-installing-kubuntu) being one, but that really doesn't help me, since I've already installed Ubuntu.

Another problem with installing all of these languages is that they all seem to come with their own fonts, clogging up my fonts menu and lagging when I'm scrolling through the menu and hit the foreign (especially Asian for some reason) fonts section.

[image]

or

[image]

I only ever work in English (`en_us-UTF8`) and speak a slight bit of French, so I'd consider keeping the French one, but I'm never going to need Portuguese, Czech, Hebrew, Finnish, or Serbian. And, if I do ever need them, I can just manually install them.

Another example:

[image]

Is there a reason why I need to download/install all these different packages and, if not, is there any way I *stop* them from being downloaded/remove them and their fonts entirely?

Comment: Is this an answer to your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/556101/how-to-prevent-unnecessary-updates/556149#556149

Comment: @JacobVlijm It helps, but that's a bit of a pain to go through and mark them all individually. I was hoping there was a way I could remove them all automatically by disabling something or editing some file.

Comment: Do you really think so? Just open Synaptic, search for language (sort), uncheck all you don't need/want in a row,. Should just take (less then) a minute.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I did, there are ton of packages that come up when you search `language`, including all the programming language ones too.